# where can I find a list of parameters for media objects in dreamweaver?

Tags: parameters, dreamweaver

Does anyone have a full list of the media object parameters for Dreamweaver? After I embed my video, I want to give it some parameters but I don't know what all of those parameters are. So far I have 3:

```
Autoplay: False, Loop: False, Controls: True
```

Does anyone have any more parameters?

Answer (score 0):

You can see another parameter and example how to use in [here](http://www.theedifier.com/blogging-blogger/attributes-embed-object-video-audio.php)